# stuck on generating timeline dialogue in visual profiler?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

My cuda program ran perfectly on visual studio 2013 but it got stuck in generating timeline dialogue everytime I try (I waited for atleast 35 minutes)?
Although i was able to get results with other cuda programs as required.

Comment: what is wrong with this question? why every one is down rating it ?

Comment: i have already added cudaDeviceReset();  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling kernel that had never ending loop in it.

Comment: How do you imagine anyone else could have answered this question based on the information you provided?